# i have tried to pause video in html when user switch browser tab and when come back on that tab video play again automatically from where it stopped

Tags: javascript, html, sass

this is script of simple video tag that I use in my html document

var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var documentTitle = document.title;

        var updateTitleForVideo = function(state) {

        if(state === 'visible')
        {
        document.title=documentTitle;
        return;
        }
        document.title = documentTitle + ' ['+  state  +']';

        };

        video.onpause = function() {
        updateTitleForVideo('Paused');
        };

        video.onplay = function() {

        updateTitleForVideo('Played');

        };

        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange' , function(){
        var state = document.visibilityState;

        if(!video.paused){

        if(state === 'hidden'){

        video.pause();
        updateTitleForVideo('Paused');
        }

        }
        if(!video.played){

        if(state === 'visible'){

        video.play();
        updateTitleForVideo('Played');
        }

        }

        });

Answer (score 0):

```js
const video  = document.getElementById("video")
//The rest of your code
// video.onpause etc...

window.addEventListener("blur", function() {
video.pause();
})

window.addEventListener("focus", function(){
video.play();
})
```

[more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event)